# How to make a time-based greeting message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display a greeting message to users. So far I have:

```
def greet
  now = Time.now
  today = Date.today.to_time

  morning = today.beginning_of_day
  noon = today.noon
  evening = today.change( hour: 17 )
  night = today.change( hour: 20 )
  tomorrow = today.tomorrow

  if (morning..noon).cover? now
    'Good Morning'
  elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
    'Good Afternoon'
  elsif (evening..night).cover? now
    'Good Evening'
  elsif (night..tomorrow).cover? now
    'Good Night'
  end
end
```

In my view I am trying to call `<%= greet %>` however, when I do this, I get an error

```
undefined local variable or method `greet'
```

I'm not sure how to display my message

```
<%= greet %>, <%= current_user.username %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be available in your HTML templates, you should add it to a helper.   Since it's such a generic method, I might suggest the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file.   This should make it available to the template.

Comment: If you're asking questions to the OP this should be a comment. Answers won't need to solicit feedback or additional information.

Comment: Edited to remove question, which was really just curiosity so that I could potentially offer further education.  An answer was provided.  Now just the answer is there.

Comment: Ahh perfect thank you! Can I ask where I can learn more about this?

Comment: The Rails documentation does a good job of explaining almost all of it:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And RailsCasts are good for seeing hands on demonstrations of each of the principals, plus how to use popular Gems:
http://railscasts.com/


To help the quality of your code, you can also do searches for three foundational principals that are keys to Ruby on Rails: 
1. "Model View Controller" or "MVC" underlying structure of Rails.
2. "Convention over Configuration"
3. "Don't Repeat Yourself" or "DRY".